# Showing black screen instead of camera in Android - using react native vision camera

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

"I'm encountering an issue with the 'react-native-vision-camera' library. It works flawlessly on all devices except the Z Fold 5, where it's displaying a black screen. I've checked the library documentation and tried various configurations, but the problem persists. Could someone please assist me in troubleshooting this issue?

Here's the library URL for reference: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-vision-camera

Any insights or guidance on how to resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

I've checked the library documentation and tried various configurations, but the problem persists.

Comment: could you provide the code you're working with?

Comment: sure. sending in a min

Comment: https://snappify.com/view/2c54b9d8-34fb-46a0-b253-7192363a5136